# Zend_Db, how to work with related tables?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I want to learn to work with related tables in the ZF to the end. (1) Can anyone help with this? 
there are 2 *users* table and *users_openid* with a link to many. I would like to implement a relationship between the tables at Zend_Db so that such users from taking it openid on Drugs findDependentRowset, add openid, openid to take the user through findParentRow ...

The manual is a Russian HELP ... but not like I can not deal with it ....( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.relationships.html

The structure of the database:

```
- 
- Table structure `users` 
- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` ( 
`Id` int (11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`Nickname` varchar (200) NOT NULL, 
`Email` varchar (200) NOT NULL DEFAULT'', 
`Active` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0 ', 
`Enabled` tinyint (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0 ', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT = 1; 

- ------------------------------------------------ -------- 

- 
- Table structure `users_openid` 
- 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_openid` ( 
`User_id` int (11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
`Openid` varchar (200) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`), 
KEY `openid` (`openid`) 
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

PS another small podvoprosik (2), with which you are creating a connection to MySQL (ubuntu), the tools have phpmyadmin and mysql administrator, but there I have not found how to do it, but do not want to write sql (

Comment: Are you asking how to use the Zend ORM?  Doctrine ORM is also available to you.

Comment: yes with Zend omr. I don't know doctrine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, How to create connection to database?

I know 2 ways how to get connection to database using Zend.

- Configure db-adapter using `zf` and then retrieving the db resource

`<?php`

```
// Initialize and retrieve DB resource
$bootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
$bootstrap->bootstrap('db');
$dbAdapter = $bootstrap->getResource('db');
?>
```

- Creating [Zend_Db Adapter from code](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html)

`<?php`

```
// Get DB resource
//   You can also use Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
$db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_MYSQL', array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'password',
            'dbname' => 'database'
        ));
?>
```

---

In your SQL you do not have any references from one table to another... I the reference imaginary? Anyways...

```
<?php
class Users extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'users';

    //
    //protected $_dependentTables = array('UsersOpenids');
}

class UsersOpenids extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_name            = 'users_openid';

    protected $_referenceMap    = array(
        'User' => array(
            'columns'           => 'User_id',
            'refTableClass'     => 'Users',
            'refColumns'        => 'Id'
        )
    );
}


//
$openIdsTable = new UsersOpenids();

//  Get only 1st Row
$openId = 'emails@gmail.com';
$openIdRow = $openIdsTable->fetchRow(array('Openid = ?' => $openId));

if ($openIdRow === null){
    throw new Exception("OpenId is not found");
}else{

//  Find parent row, will use current value of Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
//  Will get user who is associated with the open id
//  $openIdRow->findParentRow($parentTable, $ruleKey, $select)
$user = $openIdRow->findParentRow('Users', 'User');

}
?>
```

Alternatively, look at [Zend documentation on creating selects](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html). You can create a select in your model and load the data.

YDACHI